# Can gear shift labels be illuminated in Corolla 2013?

Tags: toyota, lights, corolla, gear-stick

Does anyone know if the gear shift labels can be illuminated in a Toyota Corolla 2013?  I circle the labels in the image below:

[image]

I ask because I only noticed they weren't illuminated after getting the car back from the dealership for an airbag replacement.  And I'm not sure if they accidentally broke the lighting, or if it was never illuminated in the first place.

Comment: So, first have a look under the panel to see if there is a light of some sort...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!